# Mongoose get a random element except one

Tags: node.js, mongodb, random, mongoose

I have a collection of articles in mongodb. I choose an article that i want to render,  and I want two other articles chosen randomly. I want to pick two articles in my collection that are not the same, and are not the article I have chosen before. 
Been on this problem for hours, search for a solution but only found how to pick an element randomly, but not except one...

Here is what I have now :

```
article.find({}, function(err, articles{   
    var articleChosen = articles.filter(selectArticleUrl, articleUrl)[0];
    article.find({})
    .lean()
    .distinct("_id")
    .exec(function(err, arrayIds){  
      var articleChosenIndex = arrayIds.indexOf(articleChosen._id);
      arrayIds.splice(articleChosenIndex, 1);
      chooseRdmArticle(arrayIds, function(articleRdm1Id){
        var articleRmd1 = articles.filter(selectArticleId, articleRdm1Id)[0];
        var articleRdm1Index = arrayIds.indexOf(articleRdm1Id);
        arrayIds.splice(articleRdm1Index, 1);
        chooseRdmArticle(arrayIds, function(articleRdm2Id){
          var articleRmd2 = articles.filter(selectArticleId, articleRdm2Id)[0];
          // do stuff with articleChosen, articleRmd1 and articleRmd2
        })
      })
    })
  })
```

where the function which choose rdm article is :

```
function chooseRdmArticle(articles, callback){
  var min = Math.ceil(0);
  var max = Math.floor(articles.length);
  var rdm = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  callback(articles[rdm])
}
```

and the function which select the article from its url is :

```
function selectArticleUrl(element){
  return element.url == this
}
```

My idea was to work on the array containing all the ObjectId (`arrayIds` here), to choose two Ids randomly after removing the `articleChosen` id. But I understood that `arrayIds.indexOf(articleRdm1Id);` couldn't work because ObjectIds are not strings ... Is there a method to find the index of the Id I want? Or any better idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run two queries where the first fetches the chosen document and the other uses the aggregation framework to run a pipeline with the **[`$sample`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/)** operator to return 2 random documents from the collection except the chosen one.

The following query uses Mongoose's built-in [`Promises`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) to demonstrate this:

```
let chosenArticle = article.find({ "url": articleUrl }).exec();
let randomArticles = article.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "url": { "$ne": articleUrl } } },
    { "$sample": { "size": 2 } }
]).exec();

Promise.all([chosenArticle, randomArticles]).then(articles => {
    console.log(articles);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Learned a lot by trying to understand your answer, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There is the mongodb command [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/), which is gonna read documents in a random way.

---

**Example from the documentation** :

> db.users.aggregate(    [ { $sample: { size: 3 } } ] )

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this works for me

```
const suggestedArticles = await Article.find({
  articleId: { $ne: req.params.articleId },
}).limit(2);
```